# When you try to store and show best cows and worst cows for producing milk, but get an error

Tags: java, error-handling

Im trying to create a code that records and stores the identity and the amount of milk produced by everytime a cow is milked, 2 times a day, and for 1 week( 7 days)
It also needs to show the cow that has milked the most for 1 week, and all the cows that have produced milk below 12 litres.
here is simplified code where the error is genearted:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner na = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter number of cows: ");
    int num = na.nextInt();

    int[] ID =new int[num];
    double[] Milk = new double[num];
    double[] Milk2 = new double[num];
    double[] total = new double[num];
    double[] Average = new double[num];
    double[] Lcows = new double[num];
    double[] Lmilks = new double[num];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
        System.out.println("Enter cow ID no." + (i+1));
        ID[i] = input.nextInt();

        if (ID[i] < 1000 && ID[i] > 0)
            {
            for (int u = 0; u < 7; u++)
                {
                System.out.println("DAY " + (u+1));
                System.out.println("enter milk produced for first session");
                Milk[u] = input.nextDouble();
                total[i] = total[i] + Milk[u];// error can be found here.
                System.out.println("enter milk produced for second session");
                Milk2[u] = input.nextDouble();
                total[i] = total[i] + Milk2[u];// here as well.

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was testing out the code but got this error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>           at test.main(test.java:37)

I have no idea what i am doing wrong!
I need your  smart help :):

Comment: I'd guess that the dimension on `Milk` and `Milk2` shouldn't be `num`, since you're indexing it with numbers from `0` to `6`.

Comment: What is line 41 of your code?

Comment: @Codeer Probably `Milk[u] = input.nextDouble();`, since that's where he/she gets the indexes wrong for the first time.

Comment: @Dawood If not num,  what should i put in instead?

Comment: Well, how big does an array have to be if it's going to have indexes from [0] up to [6]?